# cannot connect to mongo-express behind ingress k8s

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, mongo-express

I am trying to create the following:

1. `Deployment` for mongo
2. `Deployment` for mongo-express
3. `ClusterIp` for mongo
4. `ClusterIp` for mongo-express
5. An Ingress Service to route request to mongo-express

I want to be able to go to `xyz.com/admin/auth-db-gui` and see the mongo-express gui.

I am running this on Linux minikube.

When going to `xyz.com/admin/auth-db-gui`, I get 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable, however when executing `kubectl get pods`, I can see 2 pods running.

*I will setup the mapping for `xyz.com` in `/etc/hosts` manually as this is for only dev purpose*

db.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-db-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-db
          image: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-db-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-db
  ports:
    - name: auth-db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

db-gui

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-db-gui-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-db-gui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-db-gui
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-db-gui
          image: mongo-express
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              value: auth-db-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-db-gui-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-db-gui
  ports:
    - name: auth-db-gui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xyz-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xyz.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/auth-db-gui
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-db-gui-service
              servicePort: 8081
```

*Sorry if there is an obvious mistake above.*

Comment: What exact error are you getting ? On which platform are you working on ? Are you using specific tutorial ?

Comment: thanks i have updated the question!
1. 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable on going to the url
2. linux minikube
3. no, i am not using a specific tutorial

Comment: Have you tried to add 27017 service port instead of 8081 in Ingress yaml file ?

Comment: i tried and it didnt work for me...but should that make a difference...actually 27017 is like the "pod" port for the two, and 8081 is like the "ingress port" right?

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in [some cases](https://serverfault.com/questions/868281/kubernetes-always-gives-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-with-multiple-tls-in) 503 means that ports on configured correctly.

I've tested your ingress, along with the service and the deployment and after correcting the mistake with port in the ingress object it works great:

```sh
curl -H "Host:  xyz.com"  "192.168.49.2/admin/auth-db-gui"   
{
  "path": "/admin/auth-db-gui",
  "headers": {
    "host": "xyz.com",
    "x-request-id": "ff272df6d729af6c1fb4d5f510de88f4",
    "x-real-ip": "192.168.49.1",
    "x-forwarded-for": "192.168.49.1",
    "x-forwarded-host": "xyz.com",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-scheme": "http",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.52.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "fresh": false,
  "hostname": "xyz.com",
  "ip": "192.168.49.1",
  "os": {
    "hostname": "auth-db-gui-deployment-555c77cf75-fjbf2"
```

For testing purposes I highly recommend `mendhak/http-https-echo`. I swapped the image in your deployed and fix the port. You can test the ingress yourself with the below yaml files:

```yaml
#ingress.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xyz-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xyz.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/auth-db-gui
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-db-gui-service
              servicePort: 27017
```

Notice the how the port are being set. The `servicePort` in ingress corresponds to service `port` which is 27017.  I changed the target port of the service since echo-server works on 80

```yaml
#sevice.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-db-gui-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-db-gui
  ports:
    - name: auth-db-gui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 80
```

```yaml
#deployment.yaml
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-db-gui-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-db-gui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-db-gui
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-db-gui
          image: mendhak/http-https-echo
```

Please have a look at the docs about [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for more examples.